# Remove duplicates from ArrayFormula

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

Right now, my formula is:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, IF(REGEXMATCH(B2:D7,F2),A2:A7,"")))
```

Which returns found values, but the problem is that it returns duplicates.

For example, it would return: 'Evolution, Route 158, Route 161, Route 161, Route 161' if the value is found in multiple cells in the same row. What I would like to know is how to remove these duplicates, or make the search only search for 'unique' values.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(IF(REGEXMATCH(B2:D7,F1),A2:A7,)))))
```

EDIT: the above formula would have to create one column of the cells that match. This should work

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(join(", ", substitute(unique(transpose(split(textjoin(" ", 1, query(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(IF(REGEXMATCH(B2:D7,F1),substitute(A2:A7, " ", "|"),))),,rows(A2:A7))), " "))), "|"," ")))
```

But a better/easier way would be to try something like

```
=JOIN(", ", FILTER(A2:A7, MMULT(--regexmatch(B2:D7, F1), TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(B1:D1)^0))>0))
```

This formula 'counts' the number of matches per row and then FILTER() returns the values in A, with a count > 0. See if that helps?

Comment: Doesn't work, unfortunately. Here's the link to the document: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1auvBWTsYMgJFxxP8PRNZqMJBbeBRYou4cbVCtyyzEOY/edit?usp=sharing
You can copy it and try to mess around with the code a little if you want. It still returns duplicates.

Comment: Would be helpful to wrap this in some explanation of what this does, and why it solves the OPs problem.

Comment: Most of the formula is from OP him/herself. Just added the unique() and the transpose() which are IMO both quite self-explanatory (and/or can be googled very easily). Only thing to add would be the fact that unique requires a 'vertical range' (column), hence the use of transpose.

Comment: Sadly still the same.

Comment: @Raizeo: I don't see the new (edited) formula above applied to the cell? Can you try above formula (with added transpose) and see if it then works?

Comment: Changed it in the document now. It seems to be doing something different, as if it were scrambling the results, but duplicates still appear.

Comment: Edited my answer. Please try last formula provided.